# How to calculate line total in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I calculate the line total for creating order in woo commerce if i am using coupon code of 20 rs off and and having tax of 6%.

```
$order = new WC_Order();
$order = wc_create_order($order_data);

$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) {
    $product_id = $values['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $quantity = (int)$values['quantity'];

    $sale_price = $product->get_price();
    $final_price =  ?????
    $price_params = array( 'totals' => array( 'subtotal' => $sale_price, 'total' => $final_price ) );
    $order->add_product($product, $quantity,$price_params);
}
```

Here how can I get $final_price ?

Comment: Using WC_Cart::calculate_totals();

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
public function get_line_total( $item, $inc_tax = false, $round = true ) {
    $total = 0;

    if ( is_callable( array( $item, 'get_total' ) ) ) {
      // Check if we need to add line tax to the line total.
      $total = $inc_tax ? $item->get_total() + $item->get_total_tax() : $item->get_total();

      // Check if we need to round.
      $total = $round ? round( $total, wc_get_price_decimals() ) : $total;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_amount_line_total', $total, $this, $item, $inc_tax, $round );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

```
$order = new WC_Order();
$order = wc_create_order($order_data);

$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values) {
    $product_id = $values['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $quantity = (int)$values['quantity'];

    $sale_price = $product->get_price();
    $final_price =  ?????
    $price_params = array( 'totals' => array( 'subtotal' => $sale_price, 'total' => $final_price ) );
    $order->add_product($product, $quantity,$price_params);
}
$order_total=WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
```

Comment: Yes i have added this but when i can check in admin no discount price is added. And discount coupon when applied it applies to each product line item... so we have to add the product with arguments..

Comment: U can set discount type with fixed cart discount in coupon section in woocommerce setting.

Comment: i have added the cart discount but when i create order i have discount of 20 Rs for whole cart and 6 % tax. and product price is 50 Rs. SO how can i get the final price for this product.??